# Clip-path doesn't affect order of elements in Safari

Tags: css, z-index, clip-path

Consider the following code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8you65xt/1/)):

```js
$("*").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.classList)
  return false
})
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.positioned {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.positioned_parent {
  clip-path: inset(100% 0);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="bg">
 <div class="positioned_parent">
   <div class="positioned">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have used clip-path to remove `.positioned_parent` from view in the document. However it will still be the target of click events in Safari (but not Chrome).

I am looking for a way to use `clip-path: inset()` such that when I clip away a portion of an element the user will no longer be able to click on it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: is the inset() working fine or not?

Comment: did u try `pointer-events: none`? Don't know if Safari will ignore that too

Comment: Try the `webkit` prefix. Seems Safari [doesn't support `clip-path` without it](https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path).

Comment: @Sysix `pointer-events: none` works, but my actual use-case is to be able to clip away an arbitrary part of the element and have clicks on just that part not trigger (whereas pointer events will apply to the entire element). Here is a better fiddle I think: https://jsfiddle.net/jph37kam/ — clicking the green works correctly in Chrome and Safari, but clicking the blue above the green triggers a green click in Safari

Comment: `-webkit-clip-path` seems to work the same. Both it and the unprefixed version create the visual effect I'm looking for (so they both "work") but neither deals with click events in the correct way.